# Problem Updating Array of Varchars SQLALCHEMY

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am having some problems, when I am trying to use SQLALCHEMY to upgrade an ARRAY of VARCHARS. 
My input is for example:

```
['Particular','Comercial']
```

But in my Database it apears as:

```
['[', "'", 'P', 'a', 'r', 't', 'i', 'c', 'u', 'l', 'a', 'r', "'", ',', "'", 'C', 'o', 'm', 'e', 'r', 'c', 'i', 'a', 'l', "'", ']']
```

My flask code to update is this one:

```
@app.route('/update', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def update():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        my_data = Data.query.get(request.form.get('id_auto'))

        my_data.modelo = request.form['modelo']
        my_data.anofabricacion = request.form['anofabricacion']
        my_data.concesionario = request.form['concesionario']
        my_data.foto = request.form['foto']
        my_data.documentacion = request.form['documentacion']
        my_data.precio = request.form['precio']
        my_data.moneda = request.form['moneda']
        print(request.form['ciudadesdisp'])
        my_data.ciudadesdisp = request.form['ciudadesdisp']
        print(my_data.ciudadesdisp)
        print(my_data)
        my_data.tipocarroceria = request.form['tipocarroceria']
        my_data.sku = request.form['sku']
        print(request.form['usoauto'])
        my_data.usoauto = request.form['usoauto']
        print(my_data.usoauto)
        my_data.marca = request.form['marca']

        print(request.form.get('presentar'))

        if request.form.get('presentar') == 'on':
            print("entro if")
            my_data.presentar = True

        else:
            print("entro else")
            my_data.presentar = False

        db.session.commit()
        flash("¡Auto actualizado satisfactoriamente!")

        return redirect(url_for('Index'))
```

and here is how I declared my class:

```
class Data(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'autos'
    id_auto = db.Column(db.VARCHAR, primary_key=True)
    modelo = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(255))
    anofabricacion = db.Column(db.BIGINT)
    concesionario = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(255))
    foto = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(255))
    documentacion = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(255))
    precio = db.Column(db.BIGINT)
    moneda = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(255))
    ciudadesdisp = db.Column(db.ARRAY(VARCHAR(255)))
    tipocarroceria = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(255))
    sku = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(255))
    usoauto = db.Column(db.ARRAY(VARCHAR(255)))
    marca = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(255))
    presentar = db.Column(db.BOOLEAN)
```

Someone know why this could be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json
json.loads(request.form['ciudadesdisp'])
json.loads(request.form['usoauto'])
```

Comment: Hi @송기두, I am getting this error when trying your solution: ```raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
2020-06-09T02:38:13.048127+00:00 app[web.1]: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)```

Comment: The problem was that the input had to be like that: ```["Particular","Comercial"]```, basically with double-quotes.